# Why am I getting different results each time I try to decrypt AES data with the iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, aes

I am working on AES encryption and decryption.
I am giving single data and single key to decrypt but am getting different outputs every time.

I am using like this:

```
+(NSData*)decryptData:(NSData*)data key:(NSData*)key iv:(NSData*)iv
{
NSData* result = nil;

// setup key
unsigned char cKey[FBENCRYPT_KEY_SIZE];
bzero(cKey, sizeof(cKey));
[key getBytes:cKey length:FBENCRYPT_KEY_SIZE];

// setup iv
char cIv[FBENCRYPT_BLOCK_SIZE];
bzero(cIv, FBENCRYPT_BLOCK_SIZE);
if (iv) {
    [iv getBytes:cIv length:FBENCRYPT_BLOCK_SIZE];
}

// setup output buffer
size_t bufferSize = [data length] + FBENCRYPT_BLOCK_SIZE;
void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

// do decrypt
size_t decryptedSize = 0;
CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt,
                                      FBENCRYPT_ALGORITHM,
                                      kCCOptionECBMode,
                                      cKey,
                                      FBENCRYPT_KEY_SIZE,
                                      cIv,
                                      [data bytes],
                                      [data length],
                                      buffer,
                                      bufferSize,
                                      &decryptedSize);

if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
    result = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:decryptedSize];
} else {
    free(buffer);
    NSLog(@"[ERROR] failed to decrypt| CCCryptoStatus: %d", cryptStatus);
}

return result;
}
```

Comment: Give some examples including the key, iv, encrypted data and decrypted data. Also why use "FBENCRYPT_KEY_SIZE" instead of the Apple defines? Also is this an interoperability issue with another language such as php?

Answer (score 0):

Best guess without any example data, etc is that the key or iv are the incorrect size and/or the padding or mode is different.